# My cookie set is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

My jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$("#change-background").on('submit', function(e) {
    var src = $(this).find("input").val();
    $.cookie("_usci",src);
    //NOT HERE$("body").css("background-image", 'url($.cookie("_usci"))';
});
    //BUT HERE!! otherwise it will not work
});
```

The url need to be within these ' or these " but then the cookie will not be used good, how can I solve this?

Comment: You're not closing the parenthesis in the `css()` call. Even the editor here in SO is telling you that by displaying the entire string in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string concatenation inside of the css argument

```
$("body").css("background-image", 'url('+$.cookie("_usci")+')');
//don't forget to close your css call as Jonathan notes       ^
```

Comment: Thanks, works but I also found an error in my own code

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?:

```
$("body").css("background-image", 'url(' + $.cookie("_usci") + ')';
```

Comment: Thanks, works but I also found an error in my own code